# VBA: Populate a 'Time' column based on a range of cells and interval

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet where I need to populate a range of cells in a time column where the range is user input, and so is the time interval.

I could achieve this using a For loop, but there could potentially be ~50000+ cells, and writing to each of these cells takes a long time.

I gather there is a way to achieve this in VBA by creating an array which is the size of the range, populating this array, and then copying the array into the worksheet? I am fairly familiar with general C style programming, but not VBA specifically.

If my cells were arranged where A1 contains the start cell (1 for example) and B1 contains the end cell (100 for example), A2 contains the start time (00:00:00) and B2 contains the time interval (00:05:00) how would I use VBA to populate the cells D1:D100 like 00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00... etc.

(In reality the cell references are across sheets and a much larger range, but I can sort this later).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens after 24:00:00? Does it start over again. Also, it sounds like this is something you'll be doing repeatedly. If not, a non-VBA solution would be easy. Is that of interest?

Comment: Doug, in reality the time will really be a date. 

And yes, it will be done fairly repeatedly, with different time intervals and ranges of dates, so I'd think VBA is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Okay. Not sure why you have it as a time then. I'm going to answer it as stated above.

Comment: Doug, see my edited comment. Hit return by accident ;)

The problem is that depending on the interval the range will change, so what I'm really struggling with is that dynamic aspect of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some VBA that doesn't use arrays but is pretty fast. It uses formulas and then pastes over them as values. It takes about a second for 50,000:

```
Sub FillColumn()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FillRange As Excel.Range
Dim FirstValue As Double
Dim ValueIncrement As Double
Dim FirstCell As Long
Dim LastCell As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    FirstCell = .Range("A1")
    LastCell = .Range("B1")
    FirstValue = .Range("A2")
    ValueIncrement = .Range("B2")
End With
Set FillRange = ws.Range("D" & FirstCell).Resize((LastCell - FirstCell) + 1, 1)
With FillRange
    .Cells(1) = FirstValue
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Formula = "=R[-1]C+" & ValueIncrement
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: Explaining this line `.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Formula = "=R[-1]C+" & ValueIncrement`

`Offset(1,0)` refers to a range 1 row lower than FillRange, e.g. D2:D50001

`.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)` takes the previous and makes it one row shorter, e.g., D2:D50000

`.Formula = "=R[-1]C+" & ValueIncrement` applies a formula to that range. The formula simply says to add the ValueIncrement to the cell above. If I stop the code after this line, the formula looks like `=D1+0.0000578703703703704`. I got the R1C1-style formula used in the code by following this [most excellent tip by Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502534/293078).

Here's an array version. It seems a bit faster with 50,000. However, it's only good for 65536 elements, due to the limitations of `Application.Transpose`. I'm not sure if there's a a better way to fill the array, i.e., not using a loop:

```
Sub FillColumn2()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FillRange As Excel.Range
Dim FirstValue As Double
Dim ValueIncrement As Double
Dim FirstCell As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    FirstCell = .Range("A1")
    LastCell = .Range("B1")
    FirstValue = .Range("A2")
    ValueIncrement = .Range("B2")
End With
ReDim arr(FirstCell To LastCell)
arr(1) = FirstValue
For i = FirstCell + 1 To LastCell
    arr(i) = arr(i - 1) + ValueIncrement
Next i
Set FillRange = ws.Range("D" & FirstCell).Resize((LastCell - FirstCell) + 1, 1)
FillRange = Application.Transpose(arr)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Doug, perfect, thanks very much. The second is the kind of thing I was initially shooting for. I think it's unlikely that my list would ever be longer than 65536. However, if it's not too much to ask, could you briefly explain to me what's happening in the line that starts `.Offset` in the first example. Other than that I follow what's occurring there.

Comment: Again, thank you. Also for the source of the R1C1 notation - should come in very useful for editing some of my previous, sloppy, code.

Comment: @doug the way to avoid the transpose time hit and size limitation is to redim the array as 2d from the start `redim arr(firstcell to lastcell, 1 to 1)`