# formulaR1C1 insert concatenate string in excel vba

Tags: string, excel, concatenation, vba

I'm trying to insert a concatenated string into a cell using VBA.  Here's the formula I want to insert:

```
="ObjectID(" & E152 & ")"
```

here's what I'm trying, but I can't get it to work:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""ObjectID("" & RC[-1] & ")"
```

I've tried `"")"` and `")""` and a bunch of other combinations, but I cant get it to work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and looking at the resulting formula? See this great [Dick Kusleika SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19502534/293078) about generating R1C1 vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I did it:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""ObjectID("" & RC[-1] & "")"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub InputConcatenatedString()
    FormulaStr = """ObjectID(""&E2&"")"""
    Range("A2").Formula = "=" & FormulaStr '--Modify A2 as needed.
    Range("A2:A162").FillDown '--Modify affected range as needed.
End Sub
```

You just have to change the address of the initial cell as well as the end cell in the desired range. I just assumed that your data starts at `A2` and ends at `A162`. :)

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: actually, `ObjectID` is just a string.  this is a csv export from MongDB.

Comment: also, this has to be filled into a column so it has to be for range `E2` to `E162`..etc.

Comment: @dwstein: Which cells will contain the formula referencing to `E2:E162`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Range("A2:A162").Formula = "=""ObjectID("" & E2 & "")"""
```

Assuming you want to put your values in `A2:A162`.
Change to whatever range you got.