# VBA formula application-defined or object-defined error when inserting formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to replace results with formulas, so the user would be able to see both values and formulas.

```
Sub MoreOrEqualAmountCalculated()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Counter As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Application.Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("MonthlyData_Raw").Activate

LastRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

For Counter = 2 To LastRow
    'Populate both results and FORMULA: There is an error 1004 - application-defined or object-'defined error. What am I missing?

    Cells(Counter, 36).Formula = "=IF(Cells(Counter, 35).Value >= 0,""Recovery _
    Equals or Exceeds Amount calculated"",""Recovery less than Amount _   
    calculated"")"

Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

I have seen a few related topics but none if them explained the rules around inserting formulas in details. I would appreciate your help and explicit explanation to be able to apply this knowledge in the future.

Thank you very much,
Russ

Comment: See this excellent answer about creating formulas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19502534/293078

Comment: You really should avoid `.Activate`  Consider instead using a variable like `Dim ws1 As Worksheet` and use `Set ws1 = Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("MonthlyData_Raw")`... Then use it like this: `LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` or `ws1.Cells(Counter, 36).Formula =`

Comment: Thank you for providing ideas to streamline the code by using variables, Christmas007!!! I will apply it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Cells(Counter, 36).Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(Counter, 35).Address & " >= 0,""Recovery " & _
 "Equals or Exceeds Amount calculated"",""Recovery less than Amount " & _   
 "calculated"")"
```